# Can I export .ui file from QT Design Studio?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qt-design-studio

I've been using QT Designer to design simple GUI and save as .ui file and then convert it to Python 3 code, But now I've found QT Design Studio which seems so much easier and better. But as I've seen it just create .qml files and it's a little bit harder to work with than .py UI file. Can I export .ui file with QT Design Studio and then convert it to Python 3 code?

Comment: No, qml is a language and cannot be translated into python, unlike .ui which is a simple xml that shows the attributes of the widgets. On the other hand, python can interact with qml (there are many examples on the site so I recommend you review them)

Answer (score 1):

**At the first**, you must save your file designed as .qml file in **QT Design Studio**, then open .qml file with **QT creator** and save as .ui

At the end, you can convert ui file to py file with the below syntax

pyuic5 -o ui_form.py form.ui

Comment: Doesn't work really...