# How to export a file from Figma to PyQt?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, pyqt6, figma

I'm working in a design in Figma to use in PyQt. Is there a way to export a Figma model/design to something usable to PyQt6? I've searched extensively and found almost nothing in this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gone down the rabbit hole enough to give you a complete step by step guide, but I did find that there is [a plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/qtbridge-figma-using.html) you can use with Figma to import your designs into [qt design studio](https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/).

If I were you I would:

1. Install that plugin
2. Export my Figma Designs into the QT Design studio following their instructions.
3. Convert the design studio `.ui` file into python following the approach [outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68583052/10345775) to a related question. (although since you're using PyQt6 maybe [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66613380/downloading-qtdesigner-for-pyqt6-and-converting-ui-file-to-py-file-with-pyuic6) answers are hinting at a more relevant tool.)

Comment: The Figma plugin isn't available with the free versions of Q Design Studio (see: [Install Qt Design Studio](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/install-qt-design-studio.html)). You would need to purchase the Enterprise Edition, or buy the Qt Bridge tools separately.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I mostly just saw this didn't have any answers and tried to google around to give them some direction, but I haven't tried to do what they're specifically doing. I guess if they're willing to pay for that tool then this might still be a valid approach? If there's a way to do this without buying something I'd give that answer my support!

Comment: TBH, I think this question is off-topic, as it's essentially seeking recommendations for tools/libraries. The OP could very easily search for "qt figma" themselves and come up with the same information you did. If there's more to the question than that, the OP needs to supply more details and explain what the actual problem is.

Comment: Yeah I don't disagree with that, although if there were a simple tool for doing it I could see this answer not being too large in scope. The fact that (as far as I can tell) you need to chain a few things together to get it working, is not necessarily obvious from the perspective of the question asker.

Comment: I've googled around extensively this question and couldn't find anything that would solve my problem. I've visited the Qt Bridge webpage before (it was the first result when I googled it). I've also tried to visit both Figma and Qt's dedicated forums, and also some reddit comunities for design. It's just unfortunate that this can't be done today without the enterprise version of Qt.